# Too many TEXT fields leads to record too big

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a table with multiple 9 `TEXT` columns, each containing JSON data.  I usually `UPDATE` all the columns at once.  I can't seem to add a 10th `TEXT` column.

The table is InnoDB.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

You are near or at a limit of row size.  There is a limit of about 8000 bytes per record.  `TEXT` fields, by default, store only 767 bytes toward that 8000, and store the rest elsewhere.  You have enough TEXT fields to threaten the 8000.

**Plan A**:  Have one JSON `TEXT` field that is a structure containing the 9 structures you now have.  This will easily avoid the 8000.  And, since you seem to update all of them all the time, it is probably more efficient.  (If it could exceed 65KB, make it `MEDIUMTEXT` instead.)

**Plan B**:  `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC` or `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` would drop that 767 to 20, thereby no longer threatening to hit 8000.

**Plan C**:  "Vertical partitioning" -- That is, put some columns in a 'parallel' table.

I prefer Plan A, but it that does not fit with your access patterns, then consider the other options.

Actually, I would go with a variant of Plan A:  I would *compress* the JSON in the *client*, then store into a `BLOB` (`TEXT` won't work with compressed data).  That shrinks the disk footprint, cuts back on the network traffic, etc.

Yes, a single `UPDATE` (setting many fields of one row) is better than multiple `UPDATEs` (each setting one field of the same row).

Reference:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html

Another note:  If all 9 text fields (as you currently have it) are all longer than 767 bytes, then they are stored in 9 different places outside the record.  Plan A would lead to only 1 'overflow' place for the text.

Comment: Plan B will cause a drastic increase in disk usage. We tested this same issue recently, although row width is 64k. not sure where you got the 8k from.

Comment: 8000 excludes most of `TEXT` and `BLOB`, and possibly large `VARCHARs`.  The "about 8000" is discussed in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: The "drastic increase" probably comes from moving more text/blobs off to other storage, which is less efficiently packed.